# Mensaje embed dependiendo del comando

Tags: discord.js

Estoy programando un bot con discord.js y me he estancado en lo siguiente:

Tengo un código que tiene unas constantes con los lugares en los que aparecen los pokémon que están almacenados en un .json, las cuales entran una función random_item en el que el elige un pokemon aleatoriamente para después introducirlo en el embed mediante la variable 'appearedpokemon' y que pinte lo demás.

La cosa es que para cada lugar voy a tener que hacer un código con su correspondiente embed, repitiendo código, así que lo que quiero es una forma de que en función del lugar coja una u otra constante y no repita tanto código.

Este es el código:

```
const ruta1 = [lista.WildPokemon.Pidgey, lista.WildPokemon.Rattata]
const ruta2 = [lista.WildPokemon.Caterpie, lista.WildPokemon.Weedle]

function random_item(ruta1)
    {
      return ruta1[Math.floor(Math.random()*ruta1.length)];
    }
    
function random_item2(ruta2)
    {
      return ruta2[Math.floor(Math.random()*ruta2.length)];
    }


const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
    client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(message.content == prefix + "ruta1"){
      var appearedpokemon = random_item(Ruta1);
      
      const filter = m => m.content.includes('s!catch');
      const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({filter,  time: 15000 });
    
      const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    
      .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.username}`, iconURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`})
      .setTitle(`¡Un ${appearedpokemon.Name} salvaje apareció!\n(s!catch para capturar, límite: 20 
       segundos)\n`)
      .setImage(`${appearedpokemon.Image}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({ text: 'Bot Discord'});
    
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    
      collector.on('collect', m => { 
        message.channel.send(`¡**${message.author.username}**, has capturado un 
        ${appearedpokemon.Name}!`)
        let pokemon = db.fetch(`pokemonlist_${message.author.id}`)
        let Puntos = db.fetch(`Puntoslist_${message.author.id}`)
        db.add(`Puntoslist_${message.author.id}`, 3)
        
        if(pokemon===null||!pokemon.includes(appearedpokemon.Name)) {
        db.push(`pokemonlist_${message.author.id}`, appearedpokemon.Name)
        db.add(`pokemon_${message.author.id}`, 1)
        message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, ${appearedpokemon.Name} se ha 
        registrado en tu Pokédex.`)
       } 
       
      });
    
      collector.on('end', collected=> {
        
        message.channel.send(`El ${appearedpokemon.Name} salvaje ha huido`);
        
      });
    }})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando dos bucles: un for y un switch:

'''

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    lugar=["ruta1","ruta2","ruta3"];
    for(i = 0; i < lugar.length; i++){
    if(message.content == prefix + lugar[i]){
    switch(lugar[i]){
      case "ruta1": var appearedpokemon = random_item(Ruta1); break;
      case "ruta2": var appearedpokemon = random_item(Ruta2); break;
    }

      const filter = m => m.content.includes('s!catch');
      const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({filter,  time: 15000 });
    
      const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    
      .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.username}`, iconURL: 
      `${message.author.avatarURL()}`})
      .setTitle(`¡Un ${appearedpokemon.Name} salvaje apareció!\n(s!catch para 
       capturar, límite: 20 segundos)\n`)
      .setImage(`${appearedpokemon.Image}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({ text: 'El Sicario'});
    
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    
      collector.on('collect', m => { 
        message.channel.send(`¡**${message.author.username}**, has capturado un 
        ${appearedpokemon.Name}!`)
        let pokemon = db.fetch(`pokemonlist_${message.author.id}`)
        db.add(`Puntoslist_${message.author.id}`, 3)
        
        if(pokemon===null||!pokemon.includes(appearedpokemon.Name)) {
        db.push(`pokemonlist_${message.author.id}`, appearedpokemon.Name)
        db.add(`pokemon_${message.author.id}`, 1)
        message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, 
       ${appearedpokemon.Name} se ha registrado en tu Pokédex.`)
       } 
       collector.stop()
      });
```

'''

Luego la función random_item tendría una variable de entrada que dependería de las bucles anteriores:

'''

```
function random_item(sitio)
    {
      return sitio[Math.floor(Math.random()*sitio.length)];
    }
```

'''